# How to set size of image button in CakePHP 2.5?

Tags: css, imagebutton

I have a button named Button-Ok-icon.png (32x32 pixels). When create image submit button:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->submit('Button-Ok-icon.png');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Image not set to original size: 32x32 pixels, and scaling is very bad:
[image]

What is the way I keep image button original size?

Comment: Check out this:http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-FormHelper.html#_submit

Comment: It's not cake, it's your css that is causing it.